# cascading dropdowns in Adaptive card

Tags: botframework, chatbot, adaptive-cards

I am working on bot framework v4, i have requirement for implementing cascading dropdowns in adaptive cards.

Channel used is Web. I cannot see any help to implement the same.

Thanks
Sanjeev

Comment: If channel is used in web side this functionality you can achieve through the front-end framework like react,angular,etc. This will be difficult for MS Team channles,etc

Comment: @Kyle Delaney any help. Channel i am using as web..

Comment: @RajeeshMenoth how i can pass dropdown data from backend to front end. Correct using react it should be possible..

Comment: check dynamic data binding in adaptive card and other logic you need to write

Comment: any sample you can provide.. with minimum data.. Thanks